# C++ boost::thread and automatically locking containers

Tags: c++, stl, containers, boost-thread

Is there a way to automatically lock an STL container on access, without having to lock and release around it?

Comment: On the other hand, be aware that any shared resource is a contention point that threatens the parallelism of your application, so you'd better keep it to a minimum.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that automatically, and it is not really a problem because you very often need atomicity at a broader scope than the individual container's methods. For example, you'll typically want to search in the container before inserting into it. In that case, the search and the insertion have to be made in one atomic block, not two. Another area where an "automatically locking" container would buy nothing is when using an STL algorithm on iterators in that container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The currrent C++ standard does not say anything about thread safety for STL containers.  Officially it is possible for an STL implementation to be thread safe, but it's very unusual.  If your STL implementation is not thread safe, then you will need to "lock and release around it" or find some other way to coordinate access.

You may be interested in Intel's [Threading Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) which includes some thread safe containers similar to STL containers.

Answer (score 2):

After much Googling, it seems the way to do it is to create a wrapper around your container. e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
class thread_queue
{
private:
    std::queue<T> the_queue;
    mutable boost::mutex the_mutex;
    boost::condition_variable the_condition_variable;
public:
    void push(T const& data)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
        the_queue.push(data);
        lock.unlock();
        the_condition_variable.notify_one();
    }
    etc ...
}
```

Comment: You should own the lock when you call boost::condition_variable::notify_one()

Comment: Also, you should give your condition variable a proper name like "not_empty" and "not_full" because these are the conditions a thread might want to wait for.